# Custom build servers Vs Brand Name servers

Tags: linux

We are in the process of redoing some of our infrastructure and we need to buy some servers.

We are trying to decide if to buy brand name servers Dell, HP, or build our own. We have the expertise to build them and we know the pros and cons but I want to hear some experiences.

We are comparing the following 2 servers:

Xeon Quad 3.06 
12 Gig of Ram
Raid
Gigabyte Network

Building our self with high quality components = $23891
Buying the same specs with HP = $4720

Is it worth the difference?

Thank you.

Comment: This is pretty subjective, and thus outside the scope of the site.

Comment: $23,891? Typo? :-)

Comment: Brand name = someone to blame when things break, someone to complain on the phone to. Pay enough money you get support contracts to put blame on to get things working. Build yourself, it's your problem. That's pretty much the biggest difference. Who takes blame for what.

Comment: yeah, pretty sad this question is closed. I'm in the same situation right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that I would take into consideration is support.  I like to have support with my servers so I go with Dell or HPs.  If I put a 4 hour window on a server, and something fails, then I know I will have the part ASAP.  Also I like to have management tools available to me that are made by the manufacture such as OpenMange or HPs solution.  There are probably 3rd party hardware monitoring solutions that will work just as good but I am very comfortable with these standard ones.

Comment: Chaddada thanks for the answer. So with dell/hp they will get you parts in 4 hours? I've seen the 24-48 hours parts.. but not a 4 hour part service.

Comment: HP will do under an hour if you pay them enough.

Comment: @Chopper3 That's the *theory* anyway. We pay only for 4 hour, but it's *very* rare that they are able to meet even that. Typically they give us the excuse that the part isn't available in our local depot and that it needs to be overnighted from somewhere. Pretty frustrating.

Comment: @ErikA Location Location Location! I am in DC so we have a couple of dispatchers around us. I generally have a part in hand within 2 hours for our 4 hour servers so I can't complain.

Comment: @Chadddada - I'm in Minneapolis. Sure, it's no DC, but it's not Topeka either. We have enough Fortune 500 companies in the area that I'd expect HP to provide better service.

Comment: @ErikA - to be honest we just keep our own spares on site and pay for Next Business Day support - but then we're lucky that >90% of our kit is one model (BL460c).

Comment: It's sad this was closed.. it may not be a technical question but a question related to servers anyway.. yes it was a typo.. $2389 is the right number...  anyway for the money saved.. if I buy 3 servers (and even 1 for that matter) I can keep enough spare parts in stock to do my own 1 hour support and still save around $2,000 per machine...